# Can we overload the Point object in C# so it supports doubles?

Tags: c#, pointers, double, overloading

I am drawing some graphs using the Point object and I want to set it so 
it supports doubles as its parameters. I am working on Visual C#, WindowsConsoleApplication

Thank you.

Comment: I was going to ask whether you have a 16 million pixel wide screen so you were running out of the precision that float has, but then noticed it was for doing the graphics of a console application.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use [`PointF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.aspx). All `System.Drawing` support floating point operations. Why not use those? Otherwise, if you really want to use `double`s and pass them to integer drawing functions, you will need to create your own structure. Something to this effect:

```
struct MyPoint {
 public double X{get;set;}
 public double Y{get;set;}

 public MyPoint(double x, double y) {
   X = x;
   Y = y;
 }

 public implicit operator Point() {
  return new Point(X, Y);
 }
}
```

This is a very truncated implementation, if you have a look at the source metadata of `Point` (by going to definition), you will see all the overrides and operators you need to implement.

Also, as a point of interest, you might notice that `Point` can implicitly convert to `PointF`, but not the other way around. This is not supported due to potential loss of precision. If I were you, I would rethink the design, as it seems to go against API designers' best use practices.

Comment: Why does't MS make PointD(double version of Point)?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) structure uses int, and [PointF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckys1c1e(v=VS.100).aspx) uses float, but you can make your own that uses double.

Comment: And translate it back to the built-in Point when needed.

Comment: Nitpick: it's a structure, not a class. It's also mutable, which IMO the OP should avoid if he creates his own...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to overload point object.

Point is basically structure so it is not supporting overloading.

It is better you create your own class behaves same as point.

Hope this will help!